# Create a sample data set with selected columns

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a large data set(csv) with 10 columns, I want create a sample dataset with 5 selected columns from large set.

Is there a hdfs command for the same.

Comment: HDFS is a file system and has no concept of columns. You need some kind of transformation layer that can interact with HDFS, such as Hive.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `hdfs` cli command for this.

You'll need an external tool such as Apache Hive, Pig, Spark, Flink, Beam, Drill, etc. to read this CSV, and select out the specific columns.

If your file is only a few GB large, you could even just download the file and use `awk` or `cut` to get specific columns; don't need HDFS at all.